# Multiple States for Multiple Views On Single Page

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I'm having some trouble targeting nested views on a single page with multiple views. Here's my code.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/',
        views: {

            'viewA': {
                templateUrl: '/views/viewA.html'
            },

            'viewB': {
                templateUrl: '/views/viewB.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.sectionA1', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'viewASub': {
                templateUrl: '/views/viewA.Section1.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.sectionA2', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'viewASub': {
                templateUrl: '/views/viewA.Section2.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.sectionB1', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'viewBSub': {
                templateUrl: '/views/viewB.Section1.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.sectionB2', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'viewASub': {
                templateUrl: '/views/viewB.Section2.html'
            }
        }
    })
```

My index.html

```
<body>
  <div ui-view="viewA"></div>
  <div ui-view="viewB"></div>
</body>
```

The html to my 2 sections

```
<!-- viewA.html -->
view A content
<div ui-view="viewASub"></div>


<!-- viewB.html -->
view B content
<div ui-view="viewBSub"></div>
```

At this point all the subview states for viewA show up fine. I'm able to add multiple sections and show different states using the ui-sref link. But I'm unable get any of the 'viewB' subviews so show up. When I place the 'root.sectionB1' above 'root.sectionA1' the second section subviews show up fine. I'm assuming that I need to be more specific in how I'm referencing the parent of each subview. I'm I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You have had a copy / paste mistake in `root.sectionB2` the view should be `viewBSub` then I think it's working as expected.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/rj1zfnq1/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/',
        views: {

            'viewA': {
                templateUrl: 'views/viewA.html'
            },

            'viewB': {
                templateUrl: 'views/viewB.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.sectionA1', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'viewASub': {
                templateUrl: '/views/viewA.Section1.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.sectionA2', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'viewASub': {
                templateUrl: '/views/viewA.Section2.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.sectionB1', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'viewBSub': {
                templateUrl: '/views/viewB.Section1.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.sectionB2', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'viewBSub': { //copy / paste mistake
                templateUrl: '/views/viewB.Section2.html'
            }
        }
    })
});
```

```css
[ui-view="viewASub"] {
    color: blue;
    /*border:1px solid #000;*/
}

[ui-view="viewBSub"] {
    color: red;
    /*border:1px solid #000;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demoApp">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="views/viewA.html">
    <!-- viewA.html -->
view A content
<div ui-view="viewASub"></div>
</script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/views/viewA.Section1.html">
view A section 1
</script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/views/viewA.Section2.html">
view A section 2
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="views/viewB.html">
<!-- viewB.html -->
view B content
<div ui-view="viewBSub"></div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/views/viewB.Section1.html">
view B section 1
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/views/viewB.Section2.html">
view B section 2
</script>
<div ui-view="viewA"></div>
 <div ui-view="viewB"></div>
    <a ui-sref="root.sectionA1">sectionA1</a>
    <a ui-sref="root.sectionA2">sectionA2</a>
    <a ui-sref="root.sectionB1">sectionB1</a>
    <a ui-sref="root.sectionB2">sectionB2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realized that I wasn't specific enough in my original question that I'm looking to implement parallel states on a single page. It looks like the only solution available is using ui-router-extras, which allow for sticky states.